# How to use both root and app level env files with turborepo

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, package.json, turborepo

I have a monorepo with the following script:

```
"start": "env-cmd -f .env turbo run start --parallel",
```

If I run `yarn start` at the root, it runs all my apps using the `.env` file at the root.

A lot of my environment variables are only used in one specific app and my `/.env` file is getting cluttered as I keep on adding new apps. I want to keep that `.env` file for shared environment variables only and have children `.env` files at the root of each apps for specific configurations.

Example if I have an app called `web` located in `/apps/web`, I would like to add an `/apps/web/.env` file that is used only when building the `web` app.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can leave your global envs in monorepo root `.env` file. They will be available in all your workspaces by default.
2. You should add `dotenv-cli` package as dev_deps for workspaces that require `.env` file with workspace-specific variables.
3. Update your scripts in `package.json`:

- Add `"with-env": "dotenv -e ./.env --"`
- Update `"dev": "pnpm with-env next dev"`,
- Update `"build": "pnpm with-env next build"`

4. Remove all workspace-specific envs from monorepo root .env file (and
   from turbo.json `globalEnvs` and add .env files (with workspace-specific envs) to your workspaces to the root (package.json level).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to run both root and app level, but if you want just the app level, do the following:

1. in your root `turbo.json` put in all the keys:

```
"globalEnv": [
  "MY_KEY",
  "MY_OTHER_KEY"
],
//a. ".env" is the default, you don't need the following line unless you have a custom .env file name. e,.g. .env.local
//b. Note "globalDependencies" in the following line is referring to your .env file under the app folder, not the root one.
"globalDependencies": [".env.local"]
```

2. in your web project, put your `.env` or `.env.local` file there.

```
MY_KEY='SOMETHING'
MY_OTHER_KEY='SOMETHING ELSE'
```

3. Clear all your cache in the cache folder (just in case), then run:

`turbo run dev --filter=my-web-project`

That's it, your web app will pick up the env file in your app folder, not from your root folder.

ref: https://turbo.build/repo/docs/reference/configuration#globalEnv